# How to resample a point cloud on a coordinate plane in matlab?

Tags: matlab, 3d, point-clouds

When I read an article about 3D face recognition, I read this sentence: "The corrected 3D face is further resampled with a uniform resolution of 1mm on the xy plane". I found it on the Internet and only found out how to downsample the point cloud in the whole space. But the article said that resampling was done on the xy plane。 I tried to contact the authors but there are no response. If anyone knows, please enlighten me, thank you!

Comment: Have you considered contacting the authors?

Comment: At least give a link to this article? We can't do much with a vague description and minimal context.

Comment: I tried to contact the author but I did not get a reply。Here is the link to the article，the question is in the section of 2.1.2 and 2.3                          https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865516300551

Answer (score 0):

I guess the text means: resample point cloud of the corrected 3D face at a set of points (x,y,z).  (x, y) of these points is of uniform distribution on the xy plane. Then read z of these points.
I haven't read this article or Ref. 25 which is about pose normalization. I guess point cloud is different from the origin after pose normalization. Maybe more points so we can downsample. Maybe we can conjecture some points by interpolation.

Comment: What is the answer? @庞小震

Comment: Uniform(x,y) sampling can be done with the inbuilt Matlab function griddata.m or any other code e.g.gridfit.m (from Matlab central)